# What does nullColumnHack means?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

According to the SQLiteDatabase API documentation:

- insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)

  Convenience method for inserting a row into the database.

What does nullColumnHack means?

Can you give me an example?

Comment: API NOTE is pretty clearly at [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of many many questions,hence shows lack of research.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes you want to insert an empty row, in that case `ContentValues` have no content value, and you should use nullColumnHack.

For example, you want to insert an empty row into a table `student(id, name)`, which `id` is auto generated and `name` is null. You could invoke like this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
db.insert("student", "name", cv);
```

Comment: What happen when I specified the nullColumnHack and what happen If I dont?

Comment: @EthylCasin I guess, if you specify nullColumnHack, the final SQL statement will have a null value for that column.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @EthylCasin In the example above, android framework generates such a SQL statement: "insert into student(name) values(null)", if you dont, android framework have no idea what to fill into that statement.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try [looking at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))?

> nullColumnHack    optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.